# How to convert a reactjs to preact?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, preact

I am getting my head around preact. What would be a disadvantage replacing the reactjs Libs in my reactjs app? Or is it recommended to just use it for a production version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best to try it out in development first.  Using it only for production is an option, but I'd be concerned about testing one thing and deploying another. In terms of a disadvantage, if you're relying on the couple things React changes about events, that's not present in Preact.